# Obtener iniciales en KOTLIN

Tags: kotlin

Como obtengo las iniciales de un nombre y apellido de un usuario para, mostrarlo como imagen tipo teams y como creo la imagen(el diseño)? en KOTLIN.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Al aplicar el método get pasando el index buscado como argumento sobre el string str, el resultado es el char en la posición index del string str:

```
str.get(index)
```

Como ejemplo podría servirte este. Suponemos dos constantes, una contiene el nombre otra el apellido, aplicamos el método .get() pasando el index 0 lo que nos devuelve el char en primera posición.

```
val name: String = "Nombre"
val lastName: String = "Apellido"
print("${name.get(0)}${lastName.get(0)}")
```

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo pero preguntas mal formuladas que no se ajustan a [ask] es preferible no responderlas pues terminan cerradas

Comment: Gracias tu ejemplo me sirvió

Comment: Te recomiendo leer "cómo preguntar" que el compañero BetaM adjunta arriba para de esta manera crear una mejor comunidad :-) me alegro que te resultase útil. Un saludo !